# Could array and structures be initialized in a different way?

Tags: c, embedded, storage, riscv, linker-scripts

My question could looks weird,
indeed, here's the context:

I am currently facing a strange issue, while switching - *on the project i'm working on* - the core from pulpino to CV32 (some other changes have happend too, for instance about the crt0, like some dataram reset).

Here's a (real) example of what's happening with quite a simple main
(i cannot give the startup/crt0 files *edit: I partially gave it later in the post*).

```
#include <string.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    uintptr_t addr;
    uint32_t foo;  
} some_struct_t;

static uint32_t text_in_data[8] = {0x11111111, 0x22222222, 0x33333333, 0x44444444, 0x55555555, 0x66666666, 0x77777777, 0x88888888};
uint32_t text_in_data2[8] = {0x11111111, 0x22222222, 0x33333333, 0x44444444, 0x55555555, 0x66666666, 0x77777777, 0x88888888};

some_struct_t text_in = {(uintptr_t)text_in_data, 8};
static some_struct_t text_in2 = {(uintptr_t)text_in_data, 8};

int main(void)
{
    some_struct_t text_in3 = {(uintptr_t)text_in_data, 8};
    static some_struct_t text_in4 = {(uintptr_t)text_in_data, 8};
    static some_struct_t text_in5 = {(uintptr_t)text_in_data2, 8};

    printf("text_in_data[]: ");
    for (uint8_t i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        printf("0x%08x, ",(unsigned int)text_in_data[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("text_in_data2[]: ");
    for (uint8_t i=0;i<8;i++)
    {
        printf("0x%08x, ",(unsigned int)text_in_data2[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
    printf("text_in1.addr 0x%08x -- @text_in_data 0x%08x\n",(unsigned int)text_in.addr,(unsigned int)text_in_data);
    printf("text_in2.addr 0x%08x -- @text_in_data 0x%08x\n",(unsigned int)text_in2.addr,(unsigned int)text_in_data);
    printf("text_in3.addr 0x%08x -- @text_in_data 0x%08x\n",(unsigned int)text_in3.addr,(unsigned int)text_in_data);
    printf("text_in4.addr 0x%08x -- @text_in_data 0x%08x\n",(unsigned int)text_in4.addr,(unsigned int)text_in_data);
    printf("text_in_data2.addr 0x%08x -- @text_in_data2 0x%08x\n",(unsigned int)text_in5.addr,(unsigned int)text_in_data2);

    text_in = (some_struct_t){(uintptr_t)text_in_data, 8};
    text_in2 = (some_struct_t){(uintptr_t)text_in_data, 8};
    text_in3 = (some_struct_t){(uintptr_t)text_in_data, 8};
    text_in4 = (some_struct_t){(uintptr_t)text_in_data, 8};
    text_in5 = (some_struct_t){(uintptr_t)text_in_data2, 8};

    printf("text_in1.addr 0x%08x -- @text_in_data 0x%08x\n",(unsigned int)text_in.addr,(unsigned int)text_in_data);
    printf("text_in2.addr 0x%08x -- @text_in_data 0x%08x\n",(unsigned int)text_in2.addr,(unsigned int)text_in_data);
    printf("text_in3.addr 0x%08x -- @text_in_data 0x%08x\n",(unsigned int)text_in3.addr,(unsigned int)text_in_data);
    printf("text_in4.addr 0x%08x -- @text_in_data 0x%08x\n",(unsigned int)text_in4.addr,(unsigned int)text_in_data);
    printf("text_in_data2.addr 0x%08x -- @text_in_data2 0x%08x\n",(unsigned int)text_in5.addr,(unsigned int)text_in_data2);

    return 0;
}
```

gives

```
text_in_data[]: 0x11111111, 0x22222222, 0x33333333, 0x44444444, 0x55555555, 0x66666666, 0x77777777, 0x88888888, 
text_in_data2[]: 0x11111111, 0x22222222, 0x33333333, 0x44444444, 0x55555555, 0x66666666, 0x77777777, 0x88888888, 
text_in1.addr 0x00000000 -- @text_in_data 0x00140478
text_in2.addr 0x00000000 -- @text_in_data 0x00140478
text_in3.addr 0x00140478 -- @text_in_data 0x00140478
text_in4.addr 0x00000000 -- @text_in_data 0x00140478
text_in_data2.addr 0x00000000 -- @text_in_data2 0x00140498
text_in1.addr 0x00140478 -- @text_in_data 0x00140478
text_in2.addr 0x00140478 -- @text_in_data 0x00140478
text_in3.addr 0x00140478 -- @text_in_data 0x00140478
text_in4.addr 0x00140478 -- @text_in_data 0x00140478
text_in_data2.addr 0x00140498 -- @text_in_data2 0x00140498
```

A first issue is that `text_in<x>.addr` when defined with a static storage, are not initialized, but local defined are.

Quite a few things could explain this behavior, like for instance the fact that we are resetting the dataram in the crt0.

*edit: the reset was not due to dataram reset which is not occuring for the test firmware code, it was corrected with the fix provided later in the post*

What I can't understand though, is that `text_in_data<x>` is well initialized, but `text_in<x>` is not.

They should share the same section (=be stored in the same place, the same way), shouldn't they?

The only difference between those is that some are arrays and some are structures...

---

I looked at the differences between the original pulpino [crt0.riscv.S](https://github.com/sifive/picolibc/blob/master/libgloss/riscv/crt0.S) and the one we were using.

there was no differences that could explain such behavior, but I found this [patch](https://sourceware.org/pipermail/newlib/2021/018247.html).

Indeed, the [latest crt0.S](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pulp-platform/pulpino/master/sw/ref/crt0.riscv.S) contains a few more corrections

But by **JUST** replacing the `la a0, _edata` by `la a0, _bss_start`, that **made the code snippet work**.

Cannot really explain why such behavior though. Because of using `edata` in the bss reset loop, I think I understand that the last `edata` unaligned word was resetted as well
(`. = ALIGN(4);` between `_edata` and `_bss_start`)

**BUT** this does not explain why such different behavior before the fix between struct and array...

here's part of the linker script

```
    .data : {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        sdata  =  .;
        _sdata  =  .;
        *(.data);
        *(.data.*)
        edata  =  .;
        _edata  =  .;
    } > dataram

    .bss :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _bss_start = .;
        *(.bss)
        *(.bss.*)
        *(.sbss)
        *(.sbss.*)
        *(COMMON)
        _bss_end = .;
    } > dataram

    /* ensure there is enough room for stack */
    .stack (NOLOAD): {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        . = . + _min_stack ;
        . = ALIGN(4);
        stack = . ;
        _stack = . ;
    } > stack

    .stab  0 (NOLOAD) :
    {
        [ .stab ]
    }

    .stabstr  0 (NOLOAD) :
    {
        [ .stabstr ]
    }

    .bss :
    {
        . = ALIGN(4);
        _end = .;
    } > dataram
```

---

after doing a `riscv32-corev-elf-objdump -d *.elf`, the only difference between the two reports is the address of the beginning of the bss reset loop.
But the address changes to `0x1405bc` (for the working), and `0x14059c` (for the not working).

`0x14059c` is the address of `text_in` for those binaries.

---

**Do you have any explaination on why such differences between array and struct and why did this patch correct the issue?**

Comment: Interesting. Running with godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/PMxaohac8 produces the expected output.

Comment: @tstanisl Embedded environments have been known to behave strangely when it comes to how static data is initialized.

Comment: @tstanisl
of course, this code is quite simple and there is no obvious reason why it would not behave as expected, but its does. Hence the question.

Comment: Static initialisation occurs in crt0, so if you cannot provide that, you probably cannot be helped.

Comment: @clifford this is a first hint. thx.
i'll try to make a minimalistic crt0

Comment: maybe the entry point was overwritten when compiling the final binary?